# Convert .3ds to .fbx without losing scale

Tags: scale, unreal-engine, conversion

I'm trying to convert a bunch of .3ds files from a game to .fbx, so that I can import then into Unreal Engine. After the import into Unreal Engine all .fbx files have different sizes though.

Currently I convert my .3ds files as follows (images of the taken steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zccEk.jpg):

1. I start a new file, delete default box and import the .3ds
2. I hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> such that the thing looks normal.
3. I press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and select *geometry => origin*. I actually would like to move the mesh up the y-axis, such that the the bottom is on top of the origin. But, I don't know how to do this. How do I do this?
4. I remove all boxes I compressed in step 2.
5. I go to export to .fbx, set smoothing to 'face' and select 'mesh'.
6. I import the created .fbx into Unreal v4.22, and some objects have similar size, while others are way bigger when imported.

How do I ensure that these objects have equal size? In the game's official map editor there's no problem whatsoever with sizes. So I don't really understand why a conversion to .fbx is messing with the scales.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 3ds importer is weak or format is dead.

[image: FBX Converter 2013.3]
Try native [FBX Converter](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives). It's free, can explore, view and convert in batch 3ds, dae, dxf, fbx (old version for example) and obj to fbx up to 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but when I try to convert the .3ds with this program the result says: 'Not enough parameters'

Comment: for me it works fine: [link](https://imgur.com/a/9Ca6kPX)